# Highcharts series rendering problems

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts and Highstock and my chart is working weird; it shows vertical lines between markers.

[image: Demo chart]

As you can see, Vertical lines appears and they shouldn't.

Comment: 2 y values for the same x is the only thing I can think of. But you say that that is not the case. Best thing would be create a live demo (jsFiddle) with the same data for us to inspect.

Comment: Fiddle or live example? Possibly an artifact from dataGrouping?

Comment: Here is the live Example
https://jsfiddle.net/lvevano/0eLq70pm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is **filled** with duplicate x values, as in this snippet taken from the last few elements of your data array:

```
    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 31, 6, 38, 0), 1.32905],
    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 31, 6, 38, 0), 1.30528],
    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 31, 10, 8, 0), 1.49073],
    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 31, 10, 8, 0), 1.46641],
    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 31, 12, 5, 0), 1.33667],
    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 31, 12, 5, 0), 1.33403],
    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 31, 14, 5, 0), 1.39598],
    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 31, 14, 5, 0), 1.50467],
    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 31, 15, 40, 0), 1.29815],
    [Date.UTC(2015, 0, 31, 15, 40, 0), 1.27599],
```

Remove duplicate x values from your data if you do not want them to be plotted in this manner.